# Synergy 1.3.6 on Windows 7 - test not working

Tags: synergy

I have the Synergy client running, which says it is perfectly connected to the server when I run a test.

I run the same test on the server and it just says "running test. press stop to end test". No output log file comes up like it does on the client.

If I then stop the test, it says Synergy is about to quit with errors and warnings.  Please check the log then click OK.

However the log didn't open and I don't know how to access the log from the Command Prompt.

I'm pretty sure my configuration is correct:

```
section: links
    Joel-HP:
        left = JoelPC2
    JoelPC2:
        right = Joel-HP
end
```

My Windows 7 64-bit server is on the right, Windows 7 32-bit client on left. Both client and server are run as admin.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: some more details, slightly differently worded dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/269504/synergy-on-windows-7-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a 'screens' section as [required by the config file](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/configuration.html)?  You need to declare each PC there before you can use it in a 'links' section.

Please also use the correct codes around the config file lines so it is readable (four spaces at the start of each line, or enclose it all in backticks.)  Having it all on the same line as you have posted won't work either ;-)

Comment: I do have my screens defined and it's not all in one line.  I actually didn't make my config file.  Synergy did.  I used the screens and links UI on windows to make it.  But still no luck :(

Comment: I'm so lost on what to do :( This shouldn't be that hard and I've now put about 15 hours into it. I would really appreciate any help I can get.

I am running the newest version on synergys website. I have also tried the 1.3.6...no luck.

Wind 7 64 bit = server = Joel-HP Wind 7 32 bit = client = David-HP

My config file looks like this...as my server is to the right of my client. Also the spacing in this post doesn't look right, but in my config file the formatting is correct.

Comment: section: screens Joel-HP: switchCorners = none switchCornerSize = 0 David-HP: switchCorners = none switchCornerSize = 0 end section: links Joel-HP: left = David-HP David-HP: right = Joel-HP end section: options end

I am also running both of them as administrator. All exes are run as admin.

Everything connects perfectly fine. Log output says server is connected to client, and client is connected to server. Everything looks great.  I move my mouse to the other PC and nothing happens. It stays within the boundaries of the current server PC. So frustrating :(

Comment: Please format your config file correctly when you post - if you can't be bothered to do that, why would you expect anyone to bother helping? :-P  Try running the Synergy server in debug mode and see what happens when you attempt to switch screens.

Answer (score 0):

if willing to leave Synergy then http://www.inputdirector.com/ is also a good alternative, somewhat older though...